# Transposition Cayley graphs are planar

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, cayley-graphs

Consider the Cayley graph $G$ with vertex set the elements of the symmetric group $S_n$ and generating set the set of minimal transposition generators of the group $S_n$, that is the set $S=\{(12),(13),\ldots, (1n)\}$. Then, will the graph be always planar?

The graph is easily seen to be bipartite with one part the set of odd permutations and the other part the set of even permutations. Upto the group $S_3$ it is trivial to see why $G$  is planar. The first nontrivial part is when the group is $S_4$. The degree is $3$ in this case, but I don't see the complete regular bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$ explicitly. But can $G$ have a $K_{3,3}$ minor?  I don't think so. Also, what if I replace the set $S$ with the set of all transpositions? Any hints? thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You already have an answer regarding the first part of your question, but this uses the fact that with your given generating set, the Cayley graph is $(n-1)$-regular. What if we pick the generating set $\{ (12), (12\cdots n)\}$?

So: there is a full characterisation, due to Maschke (1896), of which finite groups admit planar Cayley graphs with respect to some generating set. Such groups are called *planar*.

> The finite group $A$ is planar if and only if $A = B_1 \times B_2$ with $B_1 = 1$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $B_2 \in \{ \mathbb{Z}_n, D_n, S_4, A_4, A_5 \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

A proof can be found e.g. [here](https://www.degruyter.com/view/title/121384?language=en), and the original article is the (aptly) named [Maschke, H.
*The Representation of Finite Groups, Especially of the Rotation Groups of the Regular Bodies of Three-and Four-Dimensional Space, by Cayley's Color Diagrams.*
Amer. J. Math. 18 (1896), no. 2, 156–194.]. If you'd like to read it, a stable link is [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369680?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

In particular, $S_n$ for $n \geq 5$ admits *no* generating set such that its Cayley graph is planar, answering the second part of your question.

Comment: thanks! just a small miss. The graphs have to connected right. otherwise we could have lot of counterexamples

Comment: @vidyarthi A Cayley graph is always connected, yes. What counterexamples do you have in mind?

Comment: why? just take $S_5$ with generating set $S=\{(12)\}$. I mean, if the generating set of the graph is not a generating set of the group, then we have a disconnected graph

Comment: @vidyarthi If your set $S$ does not generate the group, then the graph is not a Cayley graph. This is part of the definition of a Cayley graph.

Comment: oh! I am used to thinking that the set of generator of the graph need not generate the group. Anyway, thanks for pointing out that

Comment: but still, consider the graph for $S_n$ with respect to $\{(12),(123\ldots n)\}$. Now, since degree is $2$, is it not a cycle and hence, planar?

Comment: ok, got it! the generating set should be symmetric. So the inverse of $(12\ldots n)$ will be $(1\ n\ n-1\ldots 2)$, whence the degree is $3$, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi The assumption that the generating set should be symmetric is optional (though always assumed in geometric group theory). If it needs to be symmetric, then yes, we need to include $(123\dots n)^{-1})$ as well in $S$, just as you say.

Comment: Hello after a long time! I just read the mentioned reference now. As I see, the paper is quite old and uses archaic terms. Anyways, I do not get the specific charecterisation of which groups admit a Cayley diagram which can be embedded in the sphere from the paper explicitly. Could you mention which theorem specifically mentions this? Is it the ones concerning the regular color groups?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, Mashke calls "planar groups" as "regular groups". A colour group diagram is a Cayley graph. The relevant theorem is   summarised at the very beginning of §5. The Cayley graphs are drawn out at the very end of the paper (Figs I-X). Note that a graph is planar if and only if it can be embedded on the surface of a sphere.

Answer (score 10):

Your graph $G$ will not be planar for all $n \geq 5$.  To see this, we use the well-known fact that every bipartite planar graph $H$ satisfies $|E(H)| \leq 2|V(H)|-4$, and hence has average degree less than $4$.  Since your Cayley graph $G$ is $(n-1)$-regular and bipartite, it is not planar for all $n \geq 5$.

Comment: thanks, can it be said to $k-$ planar, for some $k$?

Comment: No, if $k$ is fixed, $k$-planar graphs also have bounded average degree, $O(\sqrt{k})$ if I recall correctly.